# Apex code String to char toCharArray

Tags: apex, string

In Apex code how do we convert string to array. Java toCharArray does not work.

> String string = 'somestring' to  [s, o, m, e ...]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [String.split() method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split), using `''` (two single quotes) as a parameter::

```
String ourString = 'Salesforce SE';
String[] stringCharacters = ourString.split('');
System.debug(stringCharacters);
// stringCharacters is a List<String>, each element being a substring of length 1:
// (,S,a,l,e,s,f,o,r,c,e, ,S,E)
```

Note that in API version 34.0 and earlier,the first element in the collection will be "empty":

```
String firstElement = stringCharacters.remove(0);
System.debug(stringCharacters);
// (S,a,l,e,s,f,o,r,c,e, ,S,E)
```

Comment: I just tried this in Salesforce Developer Console and got the following output: (S, a, l, e, s, f, o, r, c, e, ...) for the first debug, and (a, l, e, s, f, o, r, c, e,  , ...) for the second debug

Comment: I tried it and it does work. But, can you explain how single quote('') i.e. empty string is splitting every character. I could not understand why it is working.